Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON (in response to a basic search)
I am using the Geocoder gem (https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) version 1.8. Whenever I run Geocoder.search('Paris') in the Rails console, I get this response:
Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON
=> []


I have tried using the Geocoder gem in multiple different projects, all with the same result. It has worked in the past before. I have nothing in my Geocoder config file.
I am using Rails version 7.1.3.2 and Ruby version 3.2.2
Thank you for any help!
Edit:
I tried to log the request, and this what happened:
irb(main):009> Geocoder.search('Paris')
D, [2024-05-25T13:31:53.721929 #6543] DEBUG -- : Geocoder: HTTP request being made for https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?accept-language=en&addressdetails=1&format=json&q=Paris
W, [2024-05-25T13:31:54.067355 #6543]  WARN -- : Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON
D, [2024-05-25T13:31:54.067582 #6543] DEBUG -- : Raw response: <html>
<head>
<title>Access blocked</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Access blocked</h1>

<p>You have been blocked because you have violated the
<a href="https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/">usage policy</a>
of OSM's Nominatim geocoding service. Please be aware that OSM's resources are
limited and shared between many users. The usage policy is there to ensure that
the service remains usable for everybody.</p>

<p>Please review the terms and make sure that your
software adheres to the terms. You should in particular verify that you have set a
<b>custom HTTP referrer or HTTP user agent</b> that identifies your application, and
that you are not overusing the service with massive bulk requests.</p>

<p>If you feel that this block is unjustified or remains after you have adopted
your usage, you may contact the Nominatim system administrator at
nominatim@openstreetmap.org to have this block lifted.</p>
</body>
</head>


did you set up a configuration file, and do you have an api key for your chosen geocoding service?

@LesNightingill I only set up a blank configuration file. I am using the default geocoding service, which is nominatim and does not require an API key.

I put the code to log the HTTP request in my geocoder config file, but that's it. I've never had any issues before today.

so it appears you have found the source of the problem. You have violated the usage policy. The invalid json message is a red herring. Now you need to recover from being blocked, review the usage policy, and figure out what your violation is.

I fixed it!!! Thanks so much!!! This feels so good!!!!

I added
Geocoder.configure(http_headers: { "User-Agent" => "your contact info" })

to my Geocoder config file.

And did it work afterwards?

You might want to add a link to README_API_GUIDE.md for future visitors
